# ARIMA Unusual Forecasts

Tags: python, arima, forecast

I have the same set of data forecasted twice:

One of which is from 2017-2021 while the other is 2017-2020 (same data for 2017-2020)...

For 2020-2021 (Covid-19) the data is much higher than the previous months/years and yet the forecasted data (out-of-sample forecast using the predict() fn) shows much higher forecasts for the data ending in 2020 than that ending in 2021....

By much higher data I mean from 70,000 to millions..

How is this right? What I missing here?

Comment: Please include more details: what is the data, what code you are using, hyperparameters, train/test splits, etc.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.